# Using Google App Engine as simple key/value store

Tags: python, google-app-engine, key-value-store

I want something functionally equivalent to a `string->string` key-value store in app engine ndb, similar to Couchbase. I don't want to model anything. What options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
class KVStore(ndb.Model):
  v = ndb.TextProperty()

  @classmethod
  def get(cls, k):
    e = cls.get_by_id(k)
    return e.v if e else None

  @classmethod
  def set(cls, k, v):
    e = cls(id=k, v=v)
    e.put()
```